# Nav bar spacing

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a nav bar where the links are only separated by a small space on one line. When I try to implement this they go onto two lines with large spaces and can't seem to change this.

Comment: This question is not specific enough. Provide a picture of what you are trying to achieve and/or a reduced code example that clearly illustrates the issue.

Comment: The picture helps. To your last comment, the code is not reduced enough. If your issue is that links aren’t showing up side by side you should have a code example with only links in it and only CSS that is directly causing the problem.

Comment: in a smaller screen its:http://imgur.com/eanZJsy
so I assumed when I float left it would make them horizontal but, this occurs:http://imgur.com/SLPbpUK

Comment: delete all your css and then add more id's to your divs.
You can't call an element like this:
.navbar li ul li a 
When you have more than one element with the class .navbar

Comment: @Dominofoe if you find yourself needing to target individual elements in your CSS it’s generally an indication that you’re struggling with the language or that your project has exploded and your CSS is wrecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments and the pictures you provided I think this is what you are looking for.

```css
/* Reset Browser Default Styles
-------------------------------------- */
* { margin:0; padding:0 }


/* General Styles
-------------------------------------- */
body {
  font: 12px/1.2 Verdana, serif;
}

header {
  background: #5D2C2C;
  padding: 10px;
  /* lay out content from right to left */
  text-align: right;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}



/* Nav Styles
-------------------------------------- */
nav > * {
  display: inline-block;
  /* nav text should be left to right */
  text-align: left;
}

nav menu {
  /* dropdown menus need to be on top of page content */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  
  /* make them look nice */
  padding: 10px;
  background: #5D2C2C;
  
}

/* Show/hide the dropdown menu */
nav menu a {
  display: block;
}
nav a + menu {
  display: none;
}
nav a:hover + menu,
nav a + menu:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#introduction">Introduction</a>
    <a href="#history">History</a>
    <a href="#national_flags">National Flags</a>
    <span>
      <a href="#maritime_signal_flags">International Maritime Signal Flags</a>
      <menu>
        <a href="#maritime_signal_letters">Maritime Signal: Letters</a>
        <a href="#maritime_signal_numbers">Maritime Signal: Numbers</a>
      </menu>
    </span>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**Editable demo:** [http://jsbin.com/xojomi/2](http://jsbin.com/xojomi/2/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Good solution that includes the dropdown/nested ul in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to create a nav bar where the links are only separated by a small space on one line.

Don’t apply any CSS.

For example:

```html
<a href="">Link1</a>
<a href="">Link2</a>
<a href="">Link3</a>
<a href="">Link4</a>
```

Comment: I'm trying to do that in my code but I can't get it working as I also need it to have a drop down box etc. Could you edit mine is a JS so I can see ? Thanks

Comment: Delete **all** of your CSS. Slowly add it back in until you find your issue. Unfortunately there is no HTML element for dropdowns so adding a dropdown to your navbar will make things a little complicated.